# Grouping users together with parse.com

Tags: acl, parse-platform

I'm investigating using Parse for my next project, but one of the requirements is that users be grouped by Account, in an SaaS style application. So, a company signs up for an Account, and then creates users for all their employees, who then basically share everything.

I'm still wrapping my brain around the Parse way of doing things, but I can't find an example of how this might be done. It appears that ACLs are the way to go, but I'm not grokking exactly how.

Are there any examples of this kind of architecture using Parse? Can I even get there from here?

Comment: For reference, this question is also posted at https://www.parse.com/questions/grouping-users-together

Comment: If it gets answered there, I'll put the answer here.